# Clarification on trivial topology not being metrizable.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

This is my understanding of the proof. Please let me know if I am correct.

If I take any two points in a trivial topology. I can find the minimum radius such that they both are in two different open sets. Now if I union them, then there is no guarantee that a third point will not be a part of the new open ball. So the union of the two points might not be another open set. So we cannot have a metric space for this topology and this topology is not in Hausdorff space.

If a topological space is Hausdorff why is it not a sufficient condition to be metrizable?

Comment: What do you mean by "the minimum radius such that they both are in two different open sets"?

Comment: And what do you mean by "the new open ball"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one point space with the trivial topology is metrizable. We show that if there are $\ge 2$ points, it is not metrizable. Suppose to the contrary that it is. Let $x$ and $y$ be distinct points, and let $a=d(x,y)$. Then the open set of all $u$ such that $d(x,u)\lt a/2$ contains $x$ but not $y$, so the topology is not trivial.

Answer (score 4):

This look like at least two questions:

1. Let $X$ be a topological space with trivial topology, i.e. only $\emptyset$ and $X$ are open (and closed).
   Every metric space is Hausdorff, so if $X$ is metrizable then for every $x\in X$ the set $\{x\}$ must be closed. This is only possible if $X$  is a one-point space (and in that case of course it is metrizable). - Another way to see this: Assume $x,y\in X$ are two distinct points in a metric space $(X,d)$. Then the open ball of radius $d(x,y)>0$ around $x$ is neither empty (contains $x$) nor the whole space (does not contain $y$). Hence the topology given by the metric is not the trivial one.
2. A suitable examples for a non-metrizable Hausdorff space is the ["long line"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29)

Answer (score 2):

Metric spaces must satisfy some pretty strong properties which are not implied by Hausdorffness alone.  Among these are

- they must be *first-countable* (each point has a countable neighbourhood basis).

  For example, the [*Arens-Fort space*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190495/8348) is a Hausdorff space which is not first-countable.
- they must be *perfectly normal* (the satisfy the *normal* separation axiom, and in addition all closed sets are the countable intersection of open sets).

  For example, the [Niemytzki (or Moore) plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_plane) is a Hausdorff space which is [not perfectly normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/662075/8348).
- they are *second-countable* (have a countable basis) iff they are *separable* (have a countable dense set).  (In arbitrary topological spaces, secound-countability implies separability.)

  For example, the [Sorgenfrey line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_line) is a separable Hausdorff space which is [not second-countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/333554/8348).

  (In full generality, in a metric space the least cardinality a dense set is equal to the least cardinality of a basis.)